# Explicit/implicit loading of a dll from a mex file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, matlab, dll, mex, loadlibrary

My question is a possible duplicate of this: [matlab mex files and C++ dll (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460417/matlab-mex-files-and-c-dll-windows), however not exactly.

When I try to explicitly load a dll from a Matlab's mex file (Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7 64bit, Matlab 2010b), The loading fails at runtime (I get a NULL handle). The same code works ok when used not in the mex file.

When I try to implicitly load, by linking to the .lib file, I get a linker error of `unresolved external symbol` regarding the functions defined in the dll. Again, the same code works ok when used not in the mex file.

Is the reason the same as in the answer of the above SO question, or am I missing something? If the reason is the same, is there another solution except the one suggested in the above question?

Comment: Is the linked DLL in the path? If not then how will the system find it?

Comment: For debugging, I am using absolute path to avoid such issues, and as I wrote, the same code exactly runs ok when not used in a mex file.

Comment: Well something's different isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your code is using the Windows function `LoadLibrary`. You should check the return from [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see why the LoadLibrary call fails.

Comment: The error is: `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT
193 (0xC1) %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`
I think the dll was compiles a 32bit, and the mex is 64 bit. I will check and come with more details.

Comment: Ok, that was it. I've tried to load the 32bit dll by the 64bit mex file. When the dll is compiled with the x64 configuration, ot loads ok. Thanks!